# Deploy Django app with apache + mod_wsgi + postgresql + nginx + memchache using DotCloud

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, mod-wsgi, dotcloud

I am new to django development and overall web app development, but I am a programmer.

I want to know what are the steps to deploying a django app on [DotCloud](http://dotcloud.com) that will run on an apache server with mod_wsgi. Nginx will be used to serve media files, and Postgresql will be used for the database. This will all be used along with memchache.

This tutorial: http://dev.lethain.com/the-django-and-ubuntu-intrepid-almanac/ essentially does what I want, but I want to figure out how to get this going with DotCloud.

The Dotcloud documentation I don't feel is complete enough to provide the necessary info to accomplish this so hopefully someone will kindly provide the info.

Thank you for your help and cooperation. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Someone has, fortunately done the hardwork for you, on [how to deploy a django application on dotcloud](http://kencochrane.net/blog/2011/04/deploying-my-django-application-to-dotcloud/).

Comment: thanks for the link. I have actually come across this already and it is helpful in reiterating the key steps mentioned in the dotcloud documentation. However, it does not fit with what I need. From what I see he is just using nginx and mysql to deploy a django app. Though there is still something to be learned from this tutorial. thanks :)

Comment: @amirrustam. I believe you will find that DotCloud uses nginx/uWSGI, so you cannot use Apache/mod_wsgi. As such, the documentation referenced would be the way of doing it. Why do you specifically think you need to use Apache?

Comment: Wow, that really clears some things up. I wanted to use apache because it was one of the deployment recommendations from the django documentation, and I've always used it from my php days. Someone on reddit recommended that nginx+uWSGI was good way to go as well. I'm glad you told me this because I was reading up on nginx+uWSGI last night.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use postgreSQL with python you have to have the psycopg module installed, take a look to the doc [here](http://www.initd.org/psycopg/docs/)

Comment: thanks for that tip. I didn't know about this. I'm hoping to gather as much information from this question thread and get an actual production app going and then release a solid documentation so others can benefit.